# When you upload a file from online storage to a website, does the file get stored in the Mac?

Tags: macos, icloud, data-transfer, storage, internet

Online Storage can be dropbox, google drive whatever. You only have files saved there but not on the mac. But when you upload from the online storage directly to a website, i am guessing the file has to go thru the mac, and does it get stored somewhere in the mac, then?

Answer (score 1):

If you get prompted to download a file then it would be saved on your mac which I doubt that this is the case since these websites usually build these based on API's available from [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs) or [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) etc. where you'd be prompted to logon and usually even with some sort of authorization that the website wants gain access to your personal information